# Bootstrap Tabs First Tab dynamically loading without having to click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I use the Bootstrap tabs in my app and load some parts of the content of them dynamically via ajax calls.

It works everything fine except the first tab...
The tab is loaded, but the Ajax call is only submitted after a click on the tab.

How can i make the first tab loading the ajax content "on page load"?

Comment: Make a simple recreation in jsfiddle or somewhere else, so we can see what's happening.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/adrienne/La2765jn/) ... This is an example (not mine tho). but as you can see, the first- active tab isnt loaded. only if you click on that tab again the content will show. 

I know that the issue is the "click" in the ajax code, but how can i make the first tab load automatically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/x3pw4553/1/).

Hope it helps! (:

JS:

```
$('.active[data-toggle="tabajax"]').each(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
        targ = $this.attr('data-target');

    $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
        $(targ).html(data);
    });

    $this.tab('show');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: aaaah wow this looks nice :D 
but, can the other function be replaced or is it still needed? 
because i think on a tab click its getting active and then your function would be called aswell, not?

Comment: On click is good but you can abstract you logic in a func, so it doesn't repeat. Then just call it from both places.

Comment: The first func as it is now it won't be called a second time.